# asio io_context.run() raise a operation_abort signal?

Tags: c++, signals, boost-asio, asio

```
struct S{
  S():io_context_(){}
  void Start(){
    io_context.run();
  }
  void HandleSignal(){
    asio::signal_set signals(io_context_,SIGINT,SIGTERM)；
    signals.async_wait(){
      if(ec&&ec==asio::error::opeartion_aborted)std:cerr<<"Exception";
    };
  }
  io_context io_context_;
}
```

execute follow:

```
  S s;
  s.HandleSignal();
  s.Start();
```

but when call io_context_.run() opeation_aborted is raised.
why that happened?

Answer (score 1):

Initiated async operation was cancelled by `signal_set` destructor. That is why you get `operation_aborted`.

Your `signal_set` is local variable. It is deleted at the end of `HandleSignal` scope.

Reference of [signal_set](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_signal_set/_basic_signal_set.html) destructor states:

> This function destroys the signal set, cancelling any outstanding
>   asynchronous wait operations associated with the signal set as if by
>   calling cancel.

You could create `signal_set` as data member to prolong its lifetime:

```
struct S {
  S():io_context(), signals(io_context, SIGINT, SIGTERM){}

  void Start() {
      try {
        io_context.run();
      }
      catch (std::exception& ex) {
          std::cout << "exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
      }
  }

  void HandleSignal() {    
    signals.async_wait( [](const boost::system::error_code& ec, int ) 
    {
        if(ec&&ec==boost::asio::error::operation_aborted)
            std::cout <<"Exception";
        else 
            std::cout << "handler fired" << std::endl;
    });
  }

  boost::asio::io_context io_context;
  boost::asio::signal_set signals;
};
```